# Issues with one library unable to Open with Explorer

Tags: open-with-explorer

My users are able to use Open with Explorer on a regular basis. In one site collection, there is one library with special permissions in which the following error comes up when trying to Open with Explorer:

"Windows cannot access \mysite.site.org\DavWWWRoot\sites\etc\etc
You do not have permission to access \mysite.site.org\DavWWWRoot\sites\etc\etc. Contact your network administrator to request access."

Both the user and I have Full Control over the site and this library. There is also another library with identical access levels that we are able to Open with Explorer. The Admins recreated the library that is not working and copied over the contents exactly, and now the duplicate library is having the same issues.

We tried opening another library and navigating to this one, with the same error.

Any ideas on how this can be fixed, or why it may not be working?

Thanks

Comment: How many items are in the root of the library and how long is the average name?

Comment: There are 2300+ items in the library, no folders are being used. The longest file name was 100 characters, and I tried shortenting it to see if that was the problem with no luck. Most are much shorter.

Comment: Issue fixed - In case anyone else runs into this, it actually turns out the user had named a file with a "." at the end (i.e. filename..docx), removing the "." corrected the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed - In case anyone else runs into this, it actually turns out the user had named a file with a "." at the end (i.e. filename..docx), removing the "." corrected the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might have to do with the total size of the chunk of data being sent to Explorer exceeding a limitation in Windows.  I encountered this last year and [wrote it up](http://blog.davidjwise.com/2012/06/04/explorer-view-versus-the-large-document-library/) on my blog.  Fiddler will point you to whether or not this is the issue but if it is, the only choices are to either shorten all of your file names, increase the limit on all machines or to restructure the library so that it has fewer items in the root.